# Spring boot 2.3.10 Kafka get retry attemps with manual ack

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kafka

I have a kafka listener configured for manual ack.

```
@KafkaListener(
        topics = ["my-topic"],
        groupId = "group-id",
        containerFactory = "containerFactoryManualAck",
        clientIdPrefix = "prefix"
    )
    fun processUpdateDispatchStatusEvent(message: String, ack: Acknowledgment,
                                         @Header(KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT) attempt: Int) {
        try {
            println("attempt: $attempt")
            //logic that might fails
            ack.acknowledge();
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            ack.nack(10000)
        }
    }
```

The message is successfully redelivered with the `ack.nack(10000)` but the `DELIVERY_ATTEMPT` header is always 1

I think it's because the `DELIVERY_ATTEMPT` is not intended to be used with the `Acknowledgment.nack` but I don't find how to get the tracking of attempts using this approach.

Any suggestions?

The Springboot version is `2.3.10.RELEASE`

The spring-kafka version is `2.5.12.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

First of all that old version of Spring Boot is out of support for many years. So, you deal with some out-dated libraries. There might be some fixed in newer versions.

You don't show that you use:

```
/**
 * Set to true to populate the
 * {@link org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders#DELIVERY_ATTEMPT} header when
 * the error handler or after rollback processor implements
 * {@code DeliveryAttemptAware}. There is a small overhead so this is false by
 * default.
 * @param deliveryAttemptHeader true to populate
 * @since 2.5
 */
public void setDeliveryAttemptHeader(boolean deliveryAttemptHeader) {
```

But otherwise that `KafkaHeaders.DELIVERY_ATTEMPT` would not be `1`.